# EC2 r3.xlarge storage space not correspond to the documentation

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I'm using Hadoop YARN on EC2 over r3.xlarge instances, I launched the instances from an AMI using spark-ec2 scripts.

On https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/, the specifications of r3.xlarge are the following:

```
vCPU: 4
Mem: 30.5 GiB
Storage: 1 x 80 GB
```

The Memory is good, free command gives me this result:

```
root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            29          2         27          0          0          1
```

But the storage not correspond to the indicated one.

```
root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  6.9G  783M  91% /
devtmpfs         15G   64K   15G   1% /dev
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm
```

Is it normal to have only ~40GB and not 80GB like this was specified in the documentation ? Or this is because I launched the instance from an AMI ?

Comment: You need to mount the instance store volume, which is separate from any EBS volumes you may have attached to the server.

Comment: what AMI are you using? we don't even know the OS/distro.

Comment: I'm using a custom version of amazon ami linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two `tmpfs` directories aren't where your missing 80gb is. This is looks like an Debian/Ubuntu distro. I can reproduce something similar to your `df`:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             15G   12K   15G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G  328K  3.0G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  790M  6.6G  11% /
none             15G     0   15G   0% /run/shm
```

Note `/dev/xvda1`. That's your boot partition that is on ELB. Your 80gb SSD is actually at `/dev/xvdb`. You need to make use of it:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/ssd && mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb \
  && echo '/dev/xvdb /mnt/ssd auto defaults,nobootwait 0 0' >> /etc/fstab \
  && mount /mnt/ssd

$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             15G   12K   15G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G  328K  3.0G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  790M  6.6G  11% /
/dev/xvdb        74G   52M   70G   1% /mnt/ssd
```

Congrats! You are now the proud owner of a 80gb mount. Okay, not quite 80gb. Lets get 80gb:

```
$ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             17G   13k   17G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.3G  336k  3.3G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      8.4G  828M  7.1G  11% /
/dev/xvdb        80G   55M   76G   1% /mnt/ssd
```

Comment: LMK if you need any changes to it, @Koffee, as this is for a Debian distro. If you manage to figure it out, great. If not, I can figure out the changes.

Comment: I will try this and let you know what append, and the changes I made

Answer (score 1):

Your filesystem is probably on EBS, not the instance storage that comes with `r3.xlarge`.  This is the default for most AMIs.  Note the size of the EBS volume is not part of the image.  You can choose it when you create the instance.

Instance store is available on the larger instance types as shown here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

AMI images have two options for the root storage device.  The most common are EBS images, which use EBS for the root device.  Since EBS isn't locked to specific hardware, these instances are much more flexible.

The other option is an AMI with an instance store root storage device.   However, you lose the ability to stop the instance without terminating, change the instance type, resize the storage device, and manage the storage separately from the instance itself.

Instance store AMIs are often tagged with S3.  For example: `amzn-ami-hvm-2016.03.0.x86_64-s3` (ami-152bc275).